# How to use grouped set of images and data to train using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

So say I have an object that has been photographed from multiple angles, how do I tell tensorflow that the images combined is one object and not seperate objects? All tutorials seem to cover individual images per class.

For example this structure:

```
-vegetables
├───carrot
│   ├───carrot_1
│   │   └───image_1.jpg
│   │   └───image_2.jpg
│   │   └───image_3.jpg
│   └───carrot_2
│       └───image_1.jpg
├───potato
│   ├───potato_1
│   │   └───image_1.jpg
```

Also in the future I would like to combine these images with more sensor output.

Comment: Hey Wesley, Not sure what you want exactly. Your question statement is very very broad. What kind of network would you like to use, what is your problem statement, etc. etc.

Comment: Basically I want to classify vegetables on their quality. Train inception to determine what quality a vegetable has.


So I have different types of vegetables of which there are 1000+ sets of images and each sets consists of 30+ images. Each set of images represents one individual piece of vegetable.


So there are 500 carrot image sets each having 30+ images. Then there are 600 potato image sets etc.

Tensorflow must understand that these are individual objects because on one image a defect like rotting might be present but maybe not on a different picture

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I would re-post your question with this information and ask people what their approach to this problem would be!